# How to save names in a Qbasic file?

Tags: qbasic

I am trying to create a program in Qbasic wherein a person can enter their name and label themselves as admin or unwanted user. How do I save these preferences in my program?

Comment: I have tried using the OPEN command but I am not able to use it properly. Also, I don't.  understand the logic behind the OPEN command.

Answer (score 1):

If you have inputed the username with something like,

```
INPUT "Type your username: ", uName$
```

To save it to a file, simply use these commands:

```
OPEN "User.dat" FOR OUTPUT AS #1
  PRINT #1, uName$
CLOSE #1
```

Here's a complete program:

```
DEFINT A-Z

'Error handler for the first time we run the program.  The data file won't exist, so we create it.
ON ERROR GOTO FileNotExist

'Create a type and an Array of users that would include Username and the Status (adminstrator vs. Unwanted user)
TYPE user
  Uname AS STRING * 16
  Status AS STRING * 1
END TYPE

DIM Users(1 TO 100) AS user

'Gets all the users stored in the file.  i is a variable which represents the number of users before adding a new user
i = 0

OPEN "User.txt" FOR INPUT AS #1
WHILE NOT EOF(1)
  i = i + 1
  INPUT #1, Users(i).Uname
  INPUT #1, Users(i).Status
WEND
CLOSE #1


TryAgain:

'Gets info for the new user
CLS
INPUT "User name: ", Users(i + 1).Uname
PRINT "Admin (a), Unwanted user (u), or Regular user (r) ?"
Users(i + 1).Status = LCASE$(INPUT$(1))

'Ensure there are no blank lines in the file
IF Users(i + 1).Uname = "" OR Users(i + 1).Status = "" THEN GOTO TryAgain


'Outputs user data to the file "User.txt"
OPEN "User.txt" FOR OUTPUT AS #1
  FOR j = 1 TO i + 1
    PRINT #1, Users(j).Uname
    PRINT #1, Users(j).Status
  NEXT j
CLOSE #1


'Just for a closer: Prints all the current users.
CLS
FOR j = 1 TO i + 1
  PRINT Users(j).Uname,
  IF Users(j).Status = "a" THEN PRINT "Amdinistrator" ELSE IF Users(j).Status = "u" THEN PRINT "Unwanted User" ELSE IF Users(j).Status = "r" THEN PRINT "Regular user" ELSE PRINT Users(j).Status
NEXT j
END



'*** ERROR HANDLER: ***

FileNotExist:        
OPEN "User.txt" FOR OUTPUT AS #1
CLOSE
RESUME
```

Answer (score 1):

To save a name into a file, you will need to use the `WRITE` statement.
Eg:

```
OPEN "Name.txt" FOR OUTPUT AS #1
INPUT"Enter a name";a$
WRITE #1,a$
CLOSE #1
END
```